# Finding a specific value from interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, table

Suppose I have the given code:

```
usol[t_, x_]:= NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], x] == Sin[x], u[t, 0] == 0}, u[t, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

and I need to find the value of `usol[1,1]`. For that I tried this method:

```
answer = Through@*{usol[1, x]}

answer[1]
```

Normally `Through@*` works for interpolating functions, then why is it not evaluating here? Or in other words how can I remove the `[x]` dependence from the interpolating function to make it work?

Furthermore, how can I make a table with `x=1` and varying `t` from `0 to 5` using the interpolating function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question:

```
usol[t_, x_] :=
 NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], x] == Sin[x], u[t, 0] == 0}, u[t, x], {x, 0, 10}]

usol[1, x][[0]][1]
```

0.459698

```
usol[1, x][[0]][#] & /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Comment: For the second part of my question, I will try to use your approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's not exactly what you're asking for, but why not just use `ParametricNDSolveValue`?

```
usol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[u[x], x] == t Sin[x], u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 10}, {t}]
```

Your example doesn't really depend on `t`, so I modified it slightly to make a point.

```
usol[1][1]
(* 0.459698 *)
```

```
Table[usol[t][1], {t, 0, 5}]
(* {0., 0.459698, 0.919396, 1.37909, 1.83879, 2.29849} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

usol[1,1] does not work because the second argument of usol is used, inside usol,  as a variable. Therefore, you need to specify it as a variable. But then you can replace it by a value like e.g.:

```
usol[1, x] /. x -> 1

0.459698
```

"Through@*{usol[1, x]}" does not make sense. "@*" stands for composition. Therefore what you write in full form is: "Through[List[ usol[1, x] ]]". Now "Through" acts on the head of its argument, in this case "List". But as" List" is an atom, not composite, "Through" does nothing.